# Let a backbone.js view know about an update in a jQuery sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, backbone.js

I'm toying around with backbone.js and try to use jQuery along with it. I have a view and I'd like to react to reorder event. This is my view:

```
var SortableList = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: '#sortable_list',
  events: {
    'sortupdate': 'onDrop',
    'click':      'onClick'
  },
  initialize: function () {
    $(this.el).sortable({})
  },
  onDrop: function () {
    alert('dropped!')
  },
  onClick: function () {
    alert('clicked!')
  }
})
```

So the click event fires fine, but I just can't figure out how to track a drop/reorder/sortupdate/whatever event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best method but I currently bind the view to the update method of the Sortable:

```
$(this.el).sortable({
    update: _.bind(function(event, ui) {
        this.onDrop();
    }, this)
});
```

Comment: Where do you add this? Is this in the View.initialize(...)?

Comment: @Xeoncross Yes, just replace the OPs empty sortable constructor.